# How to add the blank space and bold in email subject

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have a email subject in trigger

```
mail.setSubject(s.Accountname+s.shiptonumber+'orderid :'+s.OrderNumber);
```

**How to add space in the email subject and how to make the subject content as bold**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can make the text bold. I am not sure where you would like to insert spaces to the subject line.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();                  

String subject = 's.Accountname + s.shiptonumber + ' <b>orderid :</b>' + s.OrderNumber';
mail.setSubject(subject);
```

Spaces can be done as so:

```
String testSpaces = 'Hello ' + Contact.FirstName + '' + Contact.LastName;
System.debug(testSpaces);
```

> Result: Hello Jim Smith;